# No module named 'airflow' after airflow installed

Tags: bash, airflow

I created a DAG with Python. When I tried to run the job, I hit the error: No module named 'airflow'. However, I'm pretty sure it is installed. How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't execute DAGs as if they were python scripts. You have to have Airflow up and running (airflow webserver && airflow scheduler) and then execute the DAG from the Airflow UI or the Airflow CLI

Comment: Thanks @JavierLopezTomas. I have my Airflow up and running (airflow webserver && airflow scheduler). Also the Dag has been imported successfully. I'm new to Airflow: just curious, what if I want to test the python job? can i run the .py in termimal?

Comment: Ohh it is solved by switching the python interpreter to the python version in the virtual environment.